# getLoaderManager().initLoader error in this callback

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-loadermanager, android-loader

it's the first time I'm using Loader. After calling the method

`getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` I'm getting an error in the argument "this".

Error after compiling:

> error: method initLoader in class LoaderManager cannot be applied to given types;
> getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
> ^
> required: int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks
> found: int,,MainActivity
> reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) D
> (argument mismatch; MainActivity cannot be converted to LoaderCallbacks)
> where D is a type-variable:
> D extends Object declared in method initLoader(int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks)

[image]

My code:

```
package com.example.newsapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<News>> {

private static final String URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search";
private NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
private TextView emptyListStateTextView;
private Intent intent;
ListView newsListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "RUN onCreate...");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    newsListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    emptyListStateTextView = findViewById(R.id.defautView);
    newsListView.setEmptyView(emptyListStateTextView);

    newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(this, new ArrayList<News>());
    newsListView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);

    newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            News currentNews = newsAdapter.getItem(position);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(currentNews.getUrl());

            intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo == null) {
        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_bar);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        emptyListStateTextView.setText("No internet connection");
    }else{

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }
    Log.e("MainActivity", "DONE onCreate...");
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle args) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "RUN onCreateLoader...");

    //TEST
    Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(URL);
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("show-tags", "contributor");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("section", "technology");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("order-by", "newest");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("from-date", "2018-01-01");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("api-key", "test");

    Log.v("my_tag", "url created is: "+uriBuilder.toString());
    //TEST
    Log.e("MainActivity", "DONE onCreateLoader...");
    return new NewsLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> data) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "RUN onLoadFinished...");
    View loadingBar = findViewById(R.id.loading_bar);
    loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    newsAdapter.clear();

    if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
        newsAdapter.addAll(data);
    }
    Log.e("MainActivity", "DONE onLoadFinished...");
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<List<News>> loader) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "RUN onLoaderReset...");
    newsAdapter.clear();
    Log.e("MainActivity", "DONE onLoaderReset...");
   }
}
```

I personally believe, that the problem must be somewhere at the imports. Even though I will really appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLoaderManager` has been depreciated, use `getSupportLoaderManager` instead like this:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

However if you still want to use this, it is due to an incorrect import. Import loader call back and it should fix the issue

```
android.app.LoaderCallbacks
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem but it can solve by using
MainActivity.this insted of simple this.